# How to set nested ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, google-cloud-firestore, ngfor

I have a Cloud Firestore DB with the following structure:

- service

  - [serviceId]

    - [userId]

      - documentId

        - service_img : "test.png"
- users

  - [uid]

    - services

      - [documentId]

        - name: "user added service name"

There is more data present in the actual DB, the above just illustrates the collection/document/field structure.

I want to get all "service_img"(which added in "userId" collection) while we execute a particular service using ngFor. Currently, when I run below code I can get images but loop continues working and my browser will crash. my code is below.

> html

```
<div *ngFor="let x of userservicelist">
    <div class="makup_nm">{{x.name}}</div>
     <div class="imageDiv">
       <img src="assets/imgs/add.png" (click)="addserviceImg(x.id)" />
    <img src="{{y.service_img}}" *ngFor="let y of getSerImgs(x.id)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

> typescript

```
getuserServices(){
   this.userservicelist=[]
   let db = firebase.firestore()
   db.collection(`users/${this.userId}/services`).get().then((res)=> 
       res.forEach((service) => {
          let temp;
          temp = service.data();
          temp.id = service.id; 
          this.userservicelist.push(temp);
          console.log(this.userservicelist)
       })
     )
   console.log(this.userservicelist)
}

getSerImgs(serviceId){
    this.serviceimage=[]
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection(`service/${serviceId}/${this.userId}`).get().then((res)=>{
      res.forEach(service => {
      let temp = service.data();
        console.log(temp)
        temp.id = service.id; 
        this.serviceimage.push(temp);
      });
    })
    return this.serviceimage
}
```

Comment: You realise `getSerImgs` will run on every change detection right?

Comment: yes, getSerImgs will run on every change detection

Comment: ... meaning every time it runs you will perform a new server request and loop. Fetch the data before you display it and you will see a massive difference.

Comment: yeah, exactly i want to fatch data in one call and want to make  one json which will include user service list and uploaded images.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested component for nested `*ngFor`

Or try to user [recursive component](https://netbasal.com/recursion-in-angular-components-1cd636269b12)